# Use of 'der' and 'des'

Tags: pronoun, vocabulary, article, idiomaticity

I was wondering, do people still use 'der' and 'des' much in sentences? The reason I ask this is, is that in Dutch, this does not get used in everyday speech, only in idioms and titles. Since German and Dutch are closely related, maybe it's also like this in German?

Comment: No, "der" and "des" are widely used in German.

Comment: By *der* you mean feminine genitive, not masculine nominative? If so, you should clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at any German text. You don't have to understand it, but just look at it, and try to find the Words you are looking for. For example, you could analyze this text (Source: [Liste der häufigsten Wörter der deutschen Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_h%C3%A4ufigsten_W%C3%B6rter_der_deutschen_Sprache) auf Wikipedia):

> Liste **der** häufigsten Wörter **der** deutschen Sprache
>
> Die Liste **der** häufigsten Wörter **der** deutschen Sprache beruht auf statistischen Auswertungen von Publikationen in deutscher Sprache.
>
> Eine Auszählung von rund elf Millionen Wörtern ergab, dass nur 207 Wortformen nach ihrer Häufigkeit (Okkurrenz) über 50 Prozent **der** deutschen Schriftsprache ausmachen. Eine solche Liste ist vor allem für die Linguistik, Kryptoanalyse und Textkompression interessant. Es sei darauf hingewiesen, dass hier die Häufigkeit von Wörtern (grammatisches Wort: Wortform) und nicht von Worten (semantisches Wort: Wortparadigma oder Lemma) ermittelt wurde und ein Rückschluss auf die Größe **des** Wortschatzes daher nur begrenzt möglich ist.
>
> ...
>
> Die 207 häufigsten Wortformen im Deutschen
>
> 30 Formen stellen 31,8 % **der** Wörter
>   *die, **der**, und, in, zu, den, das, nicht, von, sie,*
>   *ist, **des**, sich, mit, dem, dass, er, es, ein, ich,*
>   *auf, so, eine, auch, als, an, nach, wie, im, für*

This Quote has 140 words, 7 of them are »*der*« and 2 of them are »*des*«. And at the end of this quote you can read, that 31,8% of all words in German texts are one of the 30 listet words, among them »*der*« and »*des*«.

So, the answer to you question is:

The words »*der*« and »*des*« are used very often in German sentences. Both belong to the 30 most frequent used German words.